# Perl excel Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX get cell value with formula

Tags: excel, perl, cell, formula, xlsx

The Excel sheet to parse has 2 worksheets:

1. **First** Worksheet: cell A1 has following formula =TD!N2 and shows the correct value
2. **Second** Worksheet called "TD": cell N2 has following formula =SUM(F47:F49) and is a numeric value with 3 Digits after comma

   Example:
   Second worksheet "TD":
   F47 = 1,200
   F48 = 1,300
   F49 = 1,401
   N2 = SUM(F47:F49) = 3,901
   First worksheet:
   A1 = TD!N2 shows 3,901

Everything looks good but when I try to parse this Excel file with Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX

```
my $parser             = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $oBook              = $parser->parse("$excelfile");
my $worksheet          = $oBook->worksheet("first");
my $cell = $worksheet->{Cells}[1][0]; # A1
print Dumper($cell);
```

The result of the Dump Looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'Merged' => '',
             'Type' => 'Numeric',
             'Val' => 0,
             '_Value' => '0.000',
             'FormatNo' => 3,
             'Formula' => 'TD!A2',
             'Format' => bless( {
...
```

Val is 0.
How can I get the result of the formula that is 3,901? Is the cell Format of the Excel file wrong?

Comment: Note: this happens only with an Excel file written with the Excel::Writer::XLSX perl module... Very strange... I am grateful if someone already encounter such a Problem and has a solution... Thanks!